# jQuery fadeTo() performance on many elements

Tags: jquery, image, fadeto

I'm doing a cool fadey hover effect on a gallery of images to indicate which one you are hovering over - however when there are more than 20 or so images it really kills performance.

Here's how I'm doing it (very basic)

```
$('img').on('hover', function(){
    $(this).stop().fadeTo(100,1);
    $('img').not($(this)).stop().fadeTo(100,.5);
});
```

Does anyone have a good bit of optimisation for this, or a better way to do it in the first place?

Please don't say 'just use CSS', that's already there as a fallback.

Comment: Sorry, but you want to be `using CSS` falls back to the Browsers built in Graphics capabilities.. So you WANT to use CSS, NOT JS! JS as of this post does not use your graphics card but pure maths in memory(Limited and Isolated CPU Thread).. and the performance becomes poo very quickly.. USE CSS3! If user does not have CSS3 tell them to upgrade now!

Comment: @ppumkin as much as I agree with you, unfortunately i'm not in a position to force my users to upgrade (although I'd really really like to). that aside, how would I acheive this using just CSS3? stick that in an answer and I would probably accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to see if performance improves:

```
$('img').on('mouseenter', function(){     
    $(this).fadeTo(100, 0.5);
}).on('mouseleave', function(){     
    $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(100, 1);
});
```

jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/26w5q/

Seems to work fine.

Comment: aaaah, ofcourse :) makes perfect sense as you're only animating one element, not all of them. don't have my thinking cap on today... you, sir, win the internet.

Comment: Haha, easy to miss though, good luck in your jQuery escapades, it's fun! :)

Comment: You gonna have mega issues in IE6,7,8 with this solution :(

Comment: Just tested on IE7,8 and all works as fast as it did on Firefox.

Comment: maybe, just testing it now... but I could always bind mouseover etc too or use .hover() - whichever works, the important part is I don't try to animate the opacity of 80 photos at the same time :)